# TypeError:Cannot read property 'push' of null

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

when I try to push my array I have the following error :

> Cannot read property 'push' of null

I tried to solve my problem by initializing the array, but it's not working. Sorry, I'm new to code and I don't understand why it doesn't work.
Thank you for your help.

balade.ts :

```
export class Balade {
  NOM_BALADE: string;
  DATE_DEPART: string;
  LIEU_RDV: string;
  ID_BALADE?: number;

  constructor(NOM_BALADE: string, DATE_DEPART: string, LIEU_RDV: string, ID_BALADE?: number) {
      this.NOM_BALADE = NOM_BALADE;
      this.DATE_DEPART = DATE_DEPART;
      this.LIEU_RDV = LIEU_RDV;
      this.ID_BALADE = ID_BALADE;
  }
}
```

balade.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Balade } from './balade';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaladeService {
  baseUrl = './htdocs/api';
  balades: Balade[] = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<Balade[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/list.php`).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        this.balades = res['data'];
        return this.balades;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  store(balade: Balade): Observable<Balade[]> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/store.php`, { data: balade })
      .pipe(map((res) => {
        this.balades.push(res['data']);
        return this.balades;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Balade } from './balade';
import { BaladeService } from './balade.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  balades: Balade[] = [];
  error = '';
  success = '';

  balade = new Balade('', '','');

  constructor(private baladeService: BaladeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBalades();
  }

  getBalades(): void {
    this.baladeService.getAll().subscribe(
      (res: Balade[]) => {
        this.balades = res;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      }
    );
  }

  addBalade(f) {
    this.resetErrors();

    this.baladeService.store(this.balade)
      .subscribe(
        (res: Balade[]) => {
          // Update the list of balades
          this.balades = res;

          // Inform the user
          this.success = 'Created successfully';

          // Reset the form
          f.reset();
        },
        (err) => this.error = err
      );
  }
```

Here is the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    at t.project (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t._next (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t.next (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t._next (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t.next (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t._next (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t.next (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t.notifyNext (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t._next (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
    at t.next (main.6f2a73c37c9b189cf02f.js:1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with `balades` which is not working as an array as a result push property of array is not functioning.
You can make it an array by assigning an empty array.

For example

```
 this.arrayName = this.arrayName || []; //assign an empty array
```

In balade.service.ts

```
  store(balade: Balade): Observable<Balade[]> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/store.php`, { data: balade })
          .pipe(map((res) => {
            this.balades = this.balades || [];
            this.balades.push(res['data']);
            return this.balades;
          }),
          catchError(this.handleError));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
store(balade: Balade): Observable<Balade[]> {
  var ref = this; // Store the this into one variable and then use that variable to access a global scope
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/store.php`, { data: balade })
     .pipe(map((res) => {
      ref.balades.push(res['data']);
      return this.balades;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

> EDIT:

In service:

```
balades: Balade[] = [];
```

Comment: I think arrow function are preferable to aliasing `this`.

Comment: I tried it too, but i'm getting the same issue. I don't have a Stackblitz currently (I'll try to do it later), but here is my Githubhttps://github.com/Joan68/Motard-Alsace

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Sorry I think my git is not totaly up to date. export class BaladeService {
  baseUrl = './htdocs/api';
  balades: Balade[] = [];
 It figures in my current version

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes I can, do you use Discord ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use an arrow function to define your `store` method, so `this` is scoped to the function, not the class.

```
  getBalades = (): void => {
    this.baladeService.getAll().subscribe(
      (res: Balade[]) => {
        this.balades = res;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes I think I did

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the current state of the service?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let create = document.getElementById("create");
create.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  notesObj.push(addTxt.value);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  addTxt.value = "";
//   console.log(notesObj);
  showNotes();
});
```

Comment: please ans this "push of null"

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: You could edit your answare, and add some explanation to your answer